# Firefox 3.6 plugins fail on Mac?

Tags: firefox, plugins, macos, npapi, quickdraw

I just upgraded my mac to Firefox 3.6, and now neither of my TIFF Viewing plugins work.

in 3.5, If I had Quicktime on, then I'd get the tiff, viewed through quicktime. If I had Quicktime disabled, but my own plugin, AcellViewTIFF enabled, then I would get ViewTIFF viewing the TIFF. Since I'm the author of ViewTIFF, That's how I had it most of the time.

After I upgraded to 3.6, if ViewTIFF is enabled, I just get a blank space. if ViewTIFF is disabled, no matter whether or not Quicktime is enabled, it goes straight to preview.

Has anyone seen this?

(This is programming related because I'm writing AccelViewTIFF, and if the framework for plugins changed, I need to fix it...)

**Edit to add:**

This is an NPAPI plugin, I've removed or commented out the main, so I don't think that this is a CFM plugin problem.

I looked at Mozilla's "basicplugin" (located in mozilla-1-9-1-f15a2686e9a6/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/basic/mac under the standard mozilla source) and it works. I compared all of my functions to the functions in BasicPlugin, and the only function that it has that I don't is the drawPlugin function, which appears to do the actual work. All equivalent functions have the same interface.

When I remove or disable AccelViewTIFF, Firefox downloads the image and gives it to preview. When I enabled it it does nothing. This tells me that Firefox IS seeing that I have a plugin, but it's not running it for some reason.

There are no errors either in Firefox's error console or in any of the console logs I can see...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the problem was that this is an OLD plugin that still uses Quickdraw routines. evidently, they didn't make it into 64b, and so they don't work in FF 3.6.

Lets hear it for progress.

Comment: Yep, QuickDraw drawing is not only deprecated since OSX 10.4 (http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuickDraw_Ref/Reference/reference.html&usg=AFQjCNG8gCrSWfsD4IvxI0bCJVPiVcf1Iw), but also not available in 64bit enviroments (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/OtherAPIChanges/OtherAPIChanges.html&usg=AFQjCNGEvwasXoBGzyBaHSaUTYYNkrPedw)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Leopard or Snow Leopard?

TIFF files open fine with the QuickTime 7.6.3.0 plugin with Firefox 3.6.

Go to Firefox -> Preferences -> Applications.  Search for "tif" and then you can choose how Firefox handles files with the image/tiff MIME type.  Set it to the plugin of your choosing.  QuickTime should work (is for me on Snow Leopard).

Comment: Firefox doesn't give me Quicktime plugin as an option for TIFF. only preview, or other external app...

Comment: I would re-install QuickTime then.  These links will help:
http://www.apple.com/quicktime/troubleshooting/
http://support.mozilla.com/kb/QuickTime